# Converting CGM to PNG image using ImageIO

Tags: java, javax.imageio, cgm

I am trying to convert a CGM file to PNG using below function. I am keep getting NullPointerException.

```
public File convertCGMtoPNG(File cgmFile, File directoryToCreatePNG, 
                            String nameSuffix)  throws IOException 
{       
    File pngFile = new File(directoryToCreatePNG.getAbsolutePath() + 
                            File.separator +                         
        cgmFile.getName().substring(0,cgmFile.getName().lastIndexOf(".cgm")) +
                    "_" + nameSuffix + ".png");         
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(cgmFile);
        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", pngFile);
        return pngFile;
}
```

Below is the Exception i am facing

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null! at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:925)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(ImageIO.java:1608)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1540)
```

I tried to debug the code and came to know that the CGM format is not supported by ImageIO (CanDecodeInputFilter returns false for my CGM). Any idea on how to convert a CGM to PNG image.

PS: I am using java 11 for my development.

Thanks in advance

**Update**

Based on the replies I tried [jcgm](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jcgm/) libraries(added the core and image libraries to my classpath). It passes through the "**image == null!**" error but now throwing below error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width*height > Integer.MAX_VALUE!

at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageReader.getDestination(ImageReader.java:2821)
at net.sf.jcgm.imageio.plugins.cgm.CGMImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1468)
at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1315)
```

Still struggling to make it work.

Comment: Is 'image' null? Does ImageIO support cgm files? If so, you should be able to check some of the image properties, like height and width.

Comment: If CGM is not supported you need another image reading routine.

Comment: yes, the image variable is null. as I have mentioned, imageIO doesn't seem to support CGM. but here is a link that says it works http://jcgm.sourceforge.net/howto.html. but when I tried it doesn't work. any idea how to achieve it?

Comment: You need to use the jcgm library.

Comment: @matt i just tried the jcgm library (just by adding the jars in my classpath) but it throws another error as updated in question

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I am trying jcgm right now but still struggling. Do we have any other way to covert CGM to PNG that I can give a try?

Comment: Are you sure that your cgm file is a valid cgm file? It looks like the ImageIO.read should work.

Comment: @matt Yupp look like some issue with my CGM. The code works fine with sample cgm files in jcgm library. Will check my cgm. Not sure how to get rid of that **width*height > Integer.MAX_VALUE!**  error. any Idea?

Comment: @Krishnom The problem you are facing, is that you try to render into something too large for a standard `BufferedImage`. If JCGM has an option to render at a smaller size (preferably using `ImageReadParam.setSourceRenderSize(..)` or alternatively `ImageReadParam.setSourceSubsampling(...)`) you should be fine. Reading a part of the image, using `ImageReadParam.setSourceRegion(..)` may also work.

Answer (score 0):

ImageIO.read(*...) will only load these image types GIF, PNG, JPEG, BMP, and WBMP.

Any other image type will return null without error.

reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html

I do realize this is not a solution to the specific original problem but it is a solution to the question asked.

Comment: Not an answer to the question. But still an information worth noting.